# CMBlockBuffer data retention in Swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, avfoundation, h.264

How should memory ownership be handled for a `CMBlockBuffer` in Swift?

Here's an example - displaying an incoming H.264 stream in `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer`:

```swift
// 1. Copy incoming data
var dataCopy = dataFromStream
var count = dataCopy.count

// 2. Store data somewhere globally - ** crashes otherwise **
globalStorage.append(dataCopy) // globalStorage: [Data]

// 3. Create CMBLockBuffer
var blockBuffer: CMBlockBuffer!
CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock(
    allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault,
    memoryBlock: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: (dataCopy as NSData).bytes),
    blockLength: count,
    blockAllocator: kCFAllocatorDefault,
    customBlockSource: nil,
    offsetToData: 0,
    dataLength: count,
    flags: 0,
    blockBufferOut: &blockBuffer)

// 4. Create CMSampleBuffer
var sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!
CMSampleBufferCreate(
    allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault,
    dataBuffer: blockBuffer,
    dataReady: true,
    makeDataReadyCallback: nil,
    refcon: nil,
    formatDescription: myFormatDescription,
    sampleCount: 1,
    sampleTimingEntryCount: 0,
    sampleTimingArray: nil,
    sampleSizeEntryCount: 1,
    sampleSizeArray: &count,
    sampleBufferOut: &sampleBuffer)

// 5. Send to AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer...
myVideoLayer.enqueue(sampleBuffer)
```

If I remove step 2 from the above - i.e. the underlying data is not retained externally - I get the following crash after a handful of frames:

`malloc: double free for ptr 0x1490efc00`

Obviously, I can't keep appending data to a buffer forever. But if I set a cap on `globalStorage` and free old frames long after they've been displayed, I get a similar crash as soon as any array element is removed:

`malloc: *** error for object 0x132619070: pointer being freed was not allocated`

How are we supposed to work with `CMBlockBuffer` in Swift?

#### Edit

Using `kCFAllocatorNull` as the `blockAllocator` param when creating the buffer does prevent the crash.

However, we still need to keep the underlying data around until after the frames have been displayed. A circular buffer would work here, but the size needed can depend on a number of factors and change over time...

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21943532/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR so using kCFAllocatorNull does prevent the crash, but the data still needs to be retained somehow (or else the video is black). I wonder if there's a recommended approach for Swift?

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Replace steps 1 and 2 above with this:

```swift
let ptr = UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer.allocate(byteCount: count, alignment: MemoryLayout<Data>.alignment)
ptr.copyBytes(from: dataFromStream)
// Then use ptr when creating CMBlockBuffer
```

Normally we'd be in charge of freeing this memory manually, but in this case if we keep `kCFAllocatorDefault` as our `blockAllocator`, the memory will be released automatically with the `CMBlockBuffer` (after the video layer has presented and discarded the containing `CMSampleBuffer`).